# Como usar correctamente props de React dentro de un data-target?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Me gustaria saber como usar props dentro de un atributo data-target de un 'Modal'

este seria mi codigo para el boton que activa el Modal

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target={'#'+this.props.id}>{this.props.name}</button>
```

y este el de el Modal...

```
{/*Modal Start*/}
<div className="modal fade" **id={this.props.id}** role="dialog">
    <div className="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div className="modal-content">
        <div className="modal-header">
          <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 className="modal-title">{this.props.name}</h4>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-body">
          <p>This is a large modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div className="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


{/* Modal end */}
```

Ejemplo...  cuando hardcodeo data-target y  pongo "#test" y en el id dentro de el Modal pongo "test" el modal funciona correctamente. pero cuando los remplazo con valores de props, no me funciona el Modal,

Saludos..

Answer (score 0):

Me suena a que, como el modal no está cargado en el DOM de la página (ya que este existe sólo hasta que React lo renderizó), la instrucción de jQuery falla.

Prueba lo siguiente: en la sección de scripts de tu página, incluye una función:

```
showModal = function(idModal) {
    $(document).find('#' + idModal).modal();
}
```

y sustituye en React tu botón para invocar a la función en el evento `onClick`:

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-block" onClick={() => showModal(this.props.id)}>{this.props.name}</button>
```